# Compute the area of the region $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}\leq1\}.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute the area of the region
>   $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}:x^{2/3}+y^{2/3}\leq1\}.$
>
> HINT: Set $x=\cos^3{t}$ and $y=\sin^3{t}.$

The problem is easy using Greens theorem and the integral simplifies neatly to

$$A=\frac{3}{16}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(1-\cos{2t}) \ dt.$$

However, I'm not really sure how the bounds for $t$ should be in the integral. Both $x$ and $y$ go from $0$ to $1$, can I just plug this in my parameterization and obtain min/max for $t$? I get different values depending on if I use $y$ or $x$.

So my question is: how should one determin the bounds for $t?$

Comment: You just need to look at figure by putting your $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$ in your original equation.. So we get $cos^{2}t + sin^{2}t  \le1$..so it is a circle and it's easy then $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: It's $x^{2/3}$, not $x^2$.

Comment: But $x=cos^{3}t$..not just $cos t$

Comment: Thanks. But don't us actually get $1\leq 1$ in that case? How do I interpret $1\leq 1?$

Comment: Really good point...I think I cannot edit above comment..for using Green's theorem we just need the closed curve and and applying formula we get area inside that curve. So yes actually putting $x$ and $y$ in original equation, we get $cos^{2}t + sin^{2} t =1$..which is closed curve..sorry for $\le$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to describe one cycle thus, from the original parametrization for the region, we need $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Why do we have to describe one circle?

Comment: I've not checked all the derivation up to now but we need to consider al the boundary of the region wich correspond to $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: But I don't know why it corresponds to $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @Parseval I'm claiming that since we have the parametrization $x=\cos^3{t}$ and $y=\sin^3{t}$ thus for an entire cycle around the boundary we need $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: So $x=0 \implies t=0$, and $x=1 \implies t = \pi$. So $0 \leq t \leq \pi$. This is only one way, but now we have to get back to our startingpoint, and we do this by increasing our final $t$ with $\pi$. Is this correct reasoning?

Comment: Yes, indeed $\cos^3 t$ and $\sin^3 t$ are periodic with period $2\pi$ thus to describe all the boundary we need $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Gimusi.Please, your thoughts on my not very deep answer.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the constraint : $X^2+Y^2 \le 1$, $X,Y$ real.

$X^2+Y^2 =1$  is a circle.

Parametrize:

$X= \cos t$, $Y= \sin t$,  $t \in  [0,2π).$

Note:

$P$: $[0,2π) \rightarrow S$,

$S:=${$(X,Y)| X^2+Y^2 =1$} ,with

$P(t) = (\cos t,\sin t)$, is bijective.

And now consider the bijective transformation:

$x=X^3$, and $y =Y^3 $, or in terms of $t$,

the composition of the two bijective transformations:

$x=\cos^3 t, y = \sin^3 t$ , where $t \in [0,2π)$.

Comments welcome.

P.S. The above starts from a circle and ends up with the given constraint in the coordinates $x,y $(the problem).

The above steps can be done in reverse order starting from x,y ending up with the circle .

Comment: Yes Peter the fact is that the transformation is bijective and $(\cos^3t,\sin^3t)$ makes a complete cycle for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thanks.The full circle is a bit easier to visualize with X^2+Y^2=1. To get all points, we need a full circle, what you suggested.+